# How can I extract a SQLite query variable?

Tags: ios, sqlite

How can I NSLog the 'indays' variable from the SQLite query below?

Here's the query:

```
select data1,display_name,
((strftime('%s',strftime('%Y', 'now','localtime')||strftime('-%m-%d', data1))-strftime('%s','now','localtime'))/86400.0+1+((strftime('%s','now', 'localtime','+1 year')-strftime('%s','now',  'localtime'))/86400.0)) % ((strftime('%s','now', 'localtime','+1 year')-strftime('%s','now',  'localtime'))/86400.0) as indays
from contact_birthday
order by indays asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the sqlite3 documentation], especially the [C/C++ Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).

Use the [`sqlite3_column_XXX(..., ...);`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions to read the values of the columns.

```
sqlite3_stmt* selectStmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(yourdb, "SELECT ...", -1, &selectStmt, NULL);
while(SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(selectStmt)) {
  const unsigned char* txt = sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 3); // get 3rd column text
  NSString* indays = [NSString stringWithCString:txt encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);
```

Comment: The 'indays' variable is not from a column in the database.  It is derived from the 'data1' database variable (see the query above).  Is it possible to extract the 'indays' variable?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The column index to use in `sqlite_column_*` is not the index of the column in your table fields, but the index of the field in your SELECT statement (and the index of the field in the generated results table). So in your case, use 3 for your column index.

Comment: Note (as I see you're new to StackOverflow): if this solved your problem, you should mark the question as solved by ticking my answer to let others know. Thx